# it is possible to add a key value in array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

it is possible to add a key value in array following my example

```
$a = array( '1' => '5', '2' => '7', '3' => '1');
```

now i will add more array key value like this

```
$b = array( '1' => '5', '2' => '2');
```

Now i want output like this sum of same key

```
$c = array( '1' => '10', '2' => '9', '3' => '1');
```

if i want to remove array like this out put

```
$c = array( '1' => '7', '2' => '9', '3' => '1');
```

Comment: Your question is in confused manner. You should explain, what is the scenario and what you are trying to get and what error it is throwing.

Answer (score 2):

Like this for subtracting.

```
$minus = array('1'=>3);
foreach($minus as $k => $v){
   if(isset($c[$k])){
       $c[$k]-= $v;
   }else{
       $c[$k] = -$v;
   }
}
```

And this for adding:

```
$add = array('1'=>3);
foreach($add as $k => $v){
   if(isset($add[$k])){
       $c[$k]+= $v;
   }else{
       $c[$k] = $add[$k];
   }
}
```

Of course, you could wrap these in functions and have them set the new array to something different to prevent overwriting the old data.

Answer (score 2):

```
function array_add($a, $b){
    foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($a[$key]) && is_numeric($a[$key])){
            $a[$key] += $value;
        }
    }
    return $a;
}

function array_subtract($a, $b){
    foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($a[$key]) && is_numeric($a[$key])){
            $a[$key] -= $value;
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to "add" `a` and `b`:

```
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($b[$key])) {
        $c[$key] = $a[$key] + $b[$key];
    } else {
        $c[$key] = $a[$key];
    }
}
```

This will however ignore indexes that are in `b` but not in `a`.